# jQuery textarea onclick out

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Hello I have a textarea.

On Focus a new div will show up, it is a counter.

The problem is that I want to Hide this DIV again when the textarea does not have the focus anymore. So maybe onClickout?

Is there a way to achieve this?

This is what I am using to show the DIV, now I need to hide it when the textarea does not have the focus on.

```
$("#message").focus(function(){
        $(".counter").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partner of the `focus` event is the `blur` event:

```
$("#message").focus(function(){
  $(".counter").fadeIn();
}).blur(function(){
  $(".counter").fadeOut();
});
```